# Format data between SQLite and ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this... I have a SQLite database, and I'm using the standard SimpleCursorAdaptor to put the database into a ListView. No problems there. However, I would like to be able to format some of the data in between the database and the ListView. For example, I want to divide all the data in the "price" column by 100 (in the database a price might be "5400", I want it displayed as "54.00").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html):

```
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(..);
simpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex == someColumnValue) {
                TextView text = (TextView) view;  // get your View
                text.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(1)/100));  //set some data
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```