# Android use NumberFormat for an item of a ListView

Tags: android, string, floating-point, exponent

I have a String in an Editext that I convert to a float like this :

```
float montantFac = Float.valueOf(etMontantFac.getText().toString());
```

I save it in a database and later, I get it back from the DB and I assign it again to this EditText.

```
etMontantFac.setText(facture.getString(facture.getColumnIndexOrThrow("montant_fa")));
```

My problem is that it displays some numbers with exponent.
For example, *1000000* is displayed like this : *1e+06*

How can I do to ever display the values with numers only (no letter or + or anything else) ?

**EDIT :**

@Pratik : Thanks, that works fine!

I also need to do the same for an item of a ListView but I don't find how to use your solution in this case. Can you help me ?

Here is my ListView :

```
    private void fillData(){
    Cursor cuFactures = db.recupListeFacture(triFactures, argumentWhereVhc, choixVhc, argumentWhereGar, choixGar);
    startManagingCursor(cuFactures);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.facture_ligne,
            cuFactures,
            new String[] {"libelle_fa", "nom_vhc", "montant_fa", "nom_garage", "date_fa"},
            new int[] {R.id.listeNomFac, R.id.listeNomVhcFac, R.id.listeMontantFac, R.id.listeNomGarFac, R.id.listeDateFac});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The concerned field is always "montant_fa"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `DecimalFormat`? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

check this link for format

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

try this way

```
float val = facture.getFloat(facture.getColumnIndexOrThrow("montant_fa"));

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(loc);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern(pattern);
String output = df.format(value);
etMontantFac.setText(output);
```

Comment: that part DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern(pattern);
 is not necessary. The default locale format is usually enough

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here is for the [format data between sqlite and listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851543/format-data-between-sqlite-and-listview) in case someone trying to do the same thing. I had similar problem and solved it with that.

here is my example

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(....);
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
               if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex("columnname")) {
                   TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                   NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
                   tv.setText(nf.format(cursor.getInt(columnIndex)));
                   // must return true to be applied
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
        }
});
```